# read 1 bash file and compare-display the max last date corresponding in another file in third file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, unix

Scene:
There are 2 file

```
file 0.txt                                     
2015-01-01
2015-01-03
2015-01-07

file01.txt
2015-01-02
2015-01-05
```

**output file**:
the corresponding max last date in file0.txt from file 01.txt 
    2015-01-01
    2015-01-03
    file="file0.txt"
     file1="file01.txt"

The code has been implemented as given below but it is not generating any output not getting why

```
dates=()
while read -r date1     #read file01
 do
  date1="$(date +'%Y%m%d')"  **#formatting file1 content in date format** 
  COUNT=0
while read -r date12       #read file0
 do
  date12="$(date +'%Y%m%d')"
  COUNT1=0

while [[ "$date1" -lt "$date12"  ]] **#comparing the dates of file01 with file0**
 do  **                #if date12 is less than date1 then save**
  dates+=( "${dates[@]}" "$date1" ) **#all dates in an array and print them **
 date123 = "$(date +'%Y%m%d')"
 echo $date123
 COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
 done<"test.txt"
 COUNT1=$(( $COUNT1 + 1 ))
 done<"file0.txt"
 echo "${dates[@]}"
 done<"file01.txt"
```

am unable to print the max last date instead printing all last dates.still output is not available

Comment: confused on what you're looking for, there are not corresponding dates in your 2 example files. Are you looking for a date that exists in each file or are you just looking for the max date between the files?

Comment: Read each line (e.g. `while read -r line; do ...`), then convert each date to the seconds since epoch (e.g. `sec=$(date -d "$line" +%s)` ) which will give you an integer value for each date (the last being the greatest). You can either save the max `sec` for each file , or process the file in a subshell and pass the output to `sort`, in order to get the max for a file. Then just redirect the max from each file to a third file and take the max of the third and convert it back to a calendar date.

Comment: eg :   if in file 1 i have dates:1oct,5oct and in file 2 i have 2oct,4oct,7oct then in file 3 i want output 1 oct[less than 2 oct],1oct [less than 4 oct],5oct[less than 7 oct].